# How to understand japanese sentence step by step

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words

> 野菜を食べることが大切、と言われる理由は大きく三つあります。
>
> 一番目は野菜に含まれる成分のうち、体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質が摂取できるからです。ビタミン類やミネラル類はもちろん,最近はこれら以外のわずかに含まれる成分にも注意が集まっています。

1. 一番目は野菜に含まれる成分のうち

   First component that was contained in vegetables
2. 体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質が

   So I cut this part 体内に吸収されて / 重要な役割を演じる物質 -> is it true(?)

   And this mainly talk about 物質 as subject.

   The substance that was absorbed into the body which plays an important role
   摂取できるからです-> I'm a bit confused because 摂取 and 吸収 have pretty same meaning -> but I think refers to 野菜含まれる成分(？) and there is "から" at the end, so it means a component (成分) that intake.
3. The component that intake The substance that was absorbed into the body which plays an important role(?)
4. It refers to vitamin and mineral

I don't know if this true or not, and I'm pretty confuses about who is the subject in this sentence.

If it's wrong please help me revise it.

Answer (score 4):

1. 一番目 refers to one of the three reasons why they say it's important to eat vegetables.
   一番目は～～～からです。 means "The first reason is that ～～."

「[野菜に含まれる成分のうち(の)]、[体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる]物質」
(体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる is a relative clause that modifies 物質.)
"substances [in/among the elements contained in vegetables][which are absorbed into body and play important roles]"

2. 「[体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる]物質」
   "substances [which are absorbed into body and play important roles]"
3. 「一番目は・・・[(体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる)物質が摂取できる]からです。」
   "The first reason is that [you can take in the substances (which will be absorbed into body and play important roles)]."
4. Yes, 体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質 refers to vitamins and minerals, and also other micronutrients (= これら以外のわずかに含まれる成分).

Comment: Aah so 野菜に含まれる成分のうち(の)->refer to 物質？ 一番目は野菜に含まれる成分のうち~摂取できるからです(first reason is because we can take ...among elements that is contained in vegetables) 体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質が(substance that plays important role which was absorbed by body/in the body(or the same?) and 体内に吸収されて this ーて means and ? And not modifying 重要な役割を演じる？？？-----> combine them: first reason is because we can take (substance that plays important role which are absorbed by body/in the body) among elements that is contained in vegetables(?)

Comment: `野菜に含まれる成分のうち(の)->refer to 物質？` Yes. This うち is the same as 「３人のうち(の)１人が...」(≂「３人の中の１人が...」.　`substance that plays important role which was absorbed by body/in the body` -> It's more like "substance that is absorbed in body *and (then)* plays an important role." Yes, the て is "and". And the に in 体に is more like "in/into" than "by". I think it's like... "The 1st reason is because we can take in a substance that is absorbed in body *and* plays an important role among the elements contained in vegetables."  I don't know how to say this in natural English but maybe:

Comment: (cont.) "The 1st reason is because we can take in substances among those contained in vegetables which will be absorbed in body and play important roles."...?

Comment: Ah now it make senses thankyou so much!!!!!! ^^^^ お疲れ様^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4):

> 野菜を食べることが大切、と言われる理由は大きく三つあります。
>
> there are three main reasons why it is said that eating vegetables is important

So we can break the next sentence like this:

> 一番目は`???`です。
>
> The first reason is `???`.
>
> 一番目は`???`が摂取できるからです。
>
> The first reason is because we can intake `???`.
>
> 一番目は`重要な役割を演じる物質`が摂取できるからです。
>
> The first reasons is because we can intake `the substance that plays an important role`

The above is the main sentence. 
The rest adds a little more details to the main sentence.

> `体内に吸収されて`重要な役割を演じる物質
>   the substance that `is absorbed into body and` plays an important role
>
> `野菜に含まれる成分のうち`体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質
>
> `among the elements contained in vegetables`, the substance that is absorbed into body and plays an important role

The next sentence is an independent sentence. The `物質` in the first sentence doesn't necessarily refer to `ビタミン類やミネラル類`in the second sentence:

> Not only Vitamins and Minerals(not only these well known elements),
>   other elements (in vegetables) are recently getting attentions as well.
>
> ビタミン類やミネラル類はもちろん,最近はこれら以外のわずかに含まれる成分にも注意が集まっています。

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! Another question do you see the coma there? Is it affect the translation? 一番目は野菜に含まれる成分のうち、体内に吸収されて重要な役割を演じる物質が摂取できるからです like first i think that when i see the coma i should stop there or just pay attention to the 助詞 there(?) so 野菜に含まれて成分のうち=become details?